# How to list all delta tables in Databricks Azure?

Tags: apache-spark, azure-databricks, delta-lake

I have saved one dataframe in my delta lake, below is the command:

```
df2.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").partitionBy("updated_date").save("/delta/userdata/")
```

Also I can load and see the delta lake /userdata:

```
dfres=spark.read.format("delta").load("/delta/userdata")
```

but here , I have one doubt like when I am moving several parquet files from blob to delta lake creating dataframe, then how some one else would know which file I have moved and how he can work on those delta, is there any command to list all the dataframes in delta lake in databricks?

Comment: Can you do `SHOW TABLES` and see if _somehow_ Databricks tracks delta tables? They're not tracked in a metastore in the OSS version (Delta Lake 0.5.0), but have seen some code that would imply it could work with Databricks.

Answer (score 0):

Break down the problem into:

1. Find the paths of all tables you want to check. Managed tables in the default location are stored at `spark.conf.get("spark.sql.warehouse.dir") + s"/$tableName"`. If you have external tables, it is better to use `catalog.listTables()` followed by `catalog.getTableMetadata(ident).location.getPath`. Any other paths can be used directly.
2. Determine which paths belong to Delta tables using `DeltaTable.isDeltaTable(path)`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: where does `DeltaTable` come from?

Comment: ```from delta.tables import DeltaTable```.  It's the main class for programmatically interacting with Delta tables